# How do you add the sum of lists when the sublist is int?

Tags: c#

How do you add the sum of List of List when the sub list is int. I know you can't do `mainList.Sum();` because you can't add a list data type so I have to use loops and another list to get around it. If I don't want to use loops is there a simpler way of doing it ?

```
var mainList = new List<List<int>>( );
mainList.Add(new List<int>{ 6});
mainList [0].Add (5);
mainList [0].Add (3);
mainList.Add(new List<int>{ 7});
mainList [1].Add (5);
mainList [1].Add (2);
mainList.Add(new List<int>{ 8});
mainList [2].Add (5);
mainList [2].Add (19);
```

without having to do this..

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int i =0; i <3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <mainList[i].Count; j++) 
    {
        list.Add (mainList [i] [j]);
    }
}
Console.Write (list.Sum ());
```

Answer (score 5):

LINQ's `SelectMany` will flatten the object to one collection, then you can just call `Sum()` on it:

```
var result = mainList.SelectMany(i => i).Sum();
//result = 60
```

Comment: Follow up question, SelectMany goes through the entire main list and sublist. What if i only want to go through the mainList and only the first element sublist. Is it still possible to do that without loops? @Jonesopolis

Comment: @joesmhoe, you can take Slai's code and modify it to : `int sum = mainList.Sum(x => x.FirstOrDefault());`

Answer (score 1):

Or sum the sums:

```
int sum = mainList.Sum(x => x.Sum());
```